# How to Open camera on more then one ImageView on Same Activity

Tags: android, timer, camera, imageview, photo

I have multiple imageView on my layout, want to open the camera on all Imageview simultaneously. and involve a timer of friction second. so user will move his device and photo will capture and show on ImageView one by one on click "start capture" button. Like camera will open simultaneously and first imageview will capture photo and it will show it on that imageview then on second imageView will capture photo on next 2 second and show on this imageviewand so on....

I have already applied take picture by default camera by passing intent and it will open camera on another screen and capture photo will save in sdcard then we pic image and after resizing will save on that particular imageView so please don't tell me to apply this way. I don't want this. What i want i mentioned above.

**UPDATE**

I have used camera API for this task, following code i applied

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_cam);
      pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      cameraObject = isCameraAvailiable();
      showCamera = new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
      RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
      preview.addView(showCamera);
   }
```

Here ShowCamera is my class where i have implements SurfaceHolder.Callback .and write all camera related operations.I have added camera on Relative layout. Its working fine but I want to open camera and perform all operations on ImageView. What tricks should i apply here to do this. Please help..

**UPDATE**

Can we open camera on multiple ImageView simultaneously like ios. Can we get different camera image frames or preview and set them on different ImageView. So that user can feel that multiple camera are opened simultaneously.

I am using this link
[Fliping the Front Camera to Back Camera in Button Click using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843688/fliping-the-front-camera-to-back-camera-in-button-click-using-android#comment31107025_16843688)

By this i am able to open camera and switch camera from back to front. But in this question i don't get the xml layout file. I am not getting that how to open camera on different imageView.

But by the same id how to handle it with different imageView.

Comment: You need to use camera API http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html#tutorial_cameraapi

Comment: Ok, I made a sample app used by camera API I open camera by implements SurfaceHolder.Callback. and add its class object on Relative layout. it works fine but I want to open camera on Imageview. What tricks should i apply here. will you please help me.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion. :) thanks, But i need more help

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html#tutorial_cameraapi) tutorial, then follow the following steps

1. You need use a `Timer` for each two seconds call -

   `camera.takePicture(null, null,
           new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));`.
2. Photo will be captured and you will get the callback on

   ```
   @Override
     public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
   //Set data to ImageView here
   }
   ```
3. Since you need lot of `ImageViews`, it is better you use `GridView` and set photo to the items in `onPictureTaken` method.

Comment: I can't use gridview. I have updated my question. please have a look.