# Camera API captured image saving in landscape automatically

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, rotation, scale

I am using blow post to work with camera API, and flip camera to back/front. 
[Fliping the Front Camera to Back Camera in Button Click using android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843688/fliping-the-front-camera-to-back-camera-in-button-click-using-android#comment31107025_16843688)

In samsung device by default it open the camera preview in landscape but

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

by this code i am able to open camera preview in portrait. but while i am saving the image it is saving it in landscape Automatically.

by using this approch

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
            bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap,
            curntViewWidth, curntViewHeight, true);
```

processing speed is slow down. Do any one have any other way by which camera preview,capture and save image orientation will be same ..

**Do we have any library to open camera and set image in specific size like this app**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinypiece.android.mlc

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of `Camera.Parameters#setRotation()`:

> If applications want to rotate the picture to match the orientation of
>   what users see, apps should use OrientationEventListener and
>   Camera.CameraInfo

```
 public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
     if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
     int rotation = 0;
     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
     } else {  // back-facing camera
         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
     }
     mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
 }
```

`OrientationEventListener`is an abstract class that contains the `onOrientationChanged()`. This method will receive orientation changes from the system. This is one possible implementation:

```
    OrientationEventListener listener = new OrientationEventListener(this,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int i) {
           //Code from above goes here.
        }
    };
    listener.enable();
```

Comment: plz explain it more, where to write this onOrientationChanged() method , how to apply it.

Comment: Can u tell me where to set this listener?How to relate it with my code

Comment: I already told you on my answer above. You create an instance of the class and call its `enable()` to "register" it.

Comment: getting "AndroidRuntime(22343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to get camera info " by applying it